# My openstack temporary URL keeps being invalid

Tags: php, openstack

I try to generate temporary URLs for my Openstack ObjectStorage in a PHP application.
I've followed their documentation but even their python example isn't working.

So far, here is my generator :

```
class TempUrlGenerator implements ITempUrlGenerator
{
    //See https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/api/temporary_url_middleware.html for details.
    public function generate(string $url, int $validity = 5): string
    {
        $timestamp = time() + ($validity * 60);

        return sprintf(
            '%s?temp_url_sig=%s&temp_url_expires=%s',
            $url,
            $this->generateSignature($url, $timestamp),
            $timestamp
        );
    }

    private function generateSignature(string $url, int $timestamp): string
    {
        $body = sprintf(
            '%s\n%s\n%s',
            'GET',
            $timestamp,
            $this->getPath($url)
        );

        return hash_hmac('sha1', $body, trim(getenv('OPENSTACK_TEMPURL_KEY')));
    }

    private function getPath(string $url): string
    {
        $exploded = explode('/v1/', $url);

        return sprintf('/v1/%s', $exploded[1]);
    }
}
```

URL is the whole, complete URL (https://myserver.host.com/v1/...), validity is the number of minutes I want to keep my URL valid.

Beside that, the env variable is my secret key. I've already checked using a HEAD call on my account and my containers that the key is, indeed, uploaded on them with the good header. (X-Account-Meta-Temp-URL-Key and X-Container-Meta-Temp-URL-Key).

I've also checked multiple examples and implementations.

Yet I keep getting 401 invalid temp url when I try them.

Do you have any clue why or how I can troubleshot that ? Maybe is there some kind of setting on our server to check ?

Regards,

Comment: My first troubleshooting step would be printing the parameters from the PHP program, then creating a temporary URL manually using those parameters (instructions: https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/api/temporary_url_middleware.html).

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I even tried some non-PHP tools to generate the hmac ...

Comment: You mean that you can't create tempURLs manually?

Comment: Well, I tried manually (took the different bits, used some python script to generate the hmac), still I get that good ol' 401 invalid temp url.

Comment: Could that Python script be incorrect? You can use the `swift tempurl` command to generate a correct URL.

Comment: Tbh I don't know what swift is. They talk a lot about it in their doc with ever explaining what it is or how to get it... :|

Comment: Swift (upper-case S) is the nickname of the OpenStack object storage service. *swift* (lower-case s) is the command-line interface for Swift. Many *swift* sub-commands are also available in the *openstack* client, but *tempurl* is not. The *swift* client's web site is https://docs.openstack.org/python-swiftclient/latest/.

Comment: Thanks you i'll check that !